# how to prevent wrapping of world map in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I am using mapbox and featureGroup control.
World map is repeating horizontally.How can I prevent horizontal repeating of world map.
I have tried **'no-wrap:true'**  ,but this seems to work only for tile layer.
For featureGroup,Please suggest some way.

```js
var map = L.mapbox.map(mapData, MapBoxAccess.mapBoxAccess.accessId);
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo($scope.map);
```

I am adding my polygons and polylines on featureGroup

Please find attached image for better understanding.

[image: repeat world map]

Answer (score 2):

That actually is the intended behavior and features cannot repeat across the globe like this. If you wanted to prevent scrolling across the globe, you can set bounds over the map so that someone can't scroll or pan side to side.  Also, there is a Leaflet method called [WorldCopyJump](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump) which will also bounce the view back to the bounds.